# How to set epoch when using TFrecords?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using TFrecords to read dataset, code is shown below:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tfrecords_path)
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features={
        'face_gt': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'mfcc_gt': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'identity5': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    })


......


face_gt_batch, mfcc_gt_batch, identity5_batch = tf.train.batch(
        [face_gt, mfcc_gt,  identity5], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=64, capacity=2000)
```

When training, I have a `step_nums` indicating how many steps to train.

Now, I'd like to set a `epoch_nums` to indicate how many epochs to train.

But I don't know exactly how many records in TFrecords. So `epoch_nums=data_size/batch_size` can not be used.

How can I do this? Where to set the `epoch_nums`?

Here's my training code:

```
for step in np.arange(step_nums):
    if coord.should_stop():
        break

    ... sess.run() ...

    if step % 10000 == 0 or (step+1) == step_nums:
        saver.save(...)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not a direct answer, but be aware that the `tf.train*` API is deprecated. I'd suggest you consider replacing it with a `tf.data.*`input pipeline, where it's much simpler to set the number of epochs. In that case, once you have your `TFRecordDataset` instance, you just call `repeat(num_epochs)` on it.

Comment: @GPhilo, Thank you! I have change my code to `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`. By the way, I have found a way to set `epoch_nums` in `tf.train.string_input_producer()`, which is set `num_epochs=epoch_num` in `tf.train.string_input_producer()`

Comment: @GPhilo,  It seems `num_steps` is no longer need to be set when `num_epochs` and `batch_size` are set ? Because training will stop when epoch arrives at `num_epochs`. Am I understanding correctly ?